# Change C++ class pointer if represented as an iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

Say I have two classes defined as such:

```
namespace DecaveNamespace {
    class MyElt1 {
        public:
            list<MyElt2>::iterator elt2;
    }

    class MyElt2 {
        public:
            list<MyElt1>iterator elt1;
    }
}
```

In other words, for all intents and purposes, each class has a pointer to an element of the other class that is encapsulated as an iterator.

Now, say that I do some logic in a function somewhere and I want to update a pointer in `MyElt1` to point to a different instance of the class `MyElt2`. In other words:

```
// ... some logic
MyElt1 some_elt_1 = some_logic();
MyElt2 some_elt_2 = some_logic_2();

some_elt_1.elt2 = &some_elt_2;
```

If I try to do the above, I get the above compiler error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_list.h:125:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘DecaveNamespace::MyElt2*’ to ‘std::_List_iterator<DecaveNamespace::MyElt2>&&’
```

So clearly the issue is that I'm passing the wrong address back to the reference to the iterator. But then how do I update `MyElt1`'s pointer to point to a new object?

Comment: The field `MyElt2.elt2` doesn't exist in the class definitions you've shown.  You're also attempting to access it somewhat statically when it's not a static field, but you're using instance syntax.  Nothing about the line `MyElt2.elt2 = &some_elt_2;` makes any sense.

Comment: Iterators aren't pointers.

Comment: Why would you do this? Do you have an example of how this works? I'm baffled as to how this plays out. The way you've defined it will just preserve a copy presuming you have a list defined, which you don't.

Comment: @cdhowie sorry, fixed that typo.

Comment: @Decave It still doesn't work. `MyElt1` is not an object.  It is a type, and `MyElt1::elt2` is not static anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit clearly that is the case. That's why I'm asking this question. On the one hand you can think of iterators as pointers because if you dereference them you get a reference to an object. But clearly it doesn't work in reverse.

Comment: @Decave No, you can't think of iterators as pointers.

Comment: @Decave: No, I realise you think that, and I am pointing out that you are wrong. Pointers are iterators; iterators are not pointers.

Comment: @Decave You can copy the value of `some_elt_2` into the object the iterator is referencing like this: `*(some_elt_1.elt2) = some_elt_2;` (assuming a compatible copy-assignment operator), but I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: @cdhowie Nope, I want to change it to reference a different object. I don't want to update the object it's referencing.

Comment: Since, as you've discovered, your code _doesn't_ accurately represent your intention in C++ (otherwise it would compile), you'll need to use something else to explain what you're trying to do. Perhaps.. words!

Comment: @Decave Then you need a way to access the `std::list` being referenced and find the iterator you want in it. (See `std::find()`.)

Comment: So why wouldn't you change the type of `elt2` to `MyElt2 *` and likewise for `elt1`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As I said in the description of my problem, my intention is to make `some_elt_1.elt2` point to a different instance of `MyElt2`. I only showed that code to indicate that I'd tried to do that and it didn't work...

Comment: @5gon12eder I was given this class definition in a project. Trust me I would love to just use pointers, but this is what I'm stuck with.

Comment: So you're trying to obtain a `list<T>::iterator` from an arbitrary object `T`? Why didn't you just say so! Yeah, you can't do that. What would happen if the element weren't even in the list? Your compiler has no idea whether it is and, if so, where it is in that list. This is just not possible/sensible.

Comment: Then the only option I see is putting `some_elt_2` into a singleton `std::list<MyElt2>` though ugly it is.

Comment: All -- I have never seen such a passive-aggressively agro SO thread. Given that you can dereference an iterator to fetch an object, I don't think it's *that* unreasonable to ask about the reverse case.

Comment: Not unreasonable at all. The kicker here is the iterator knows about the object. That's no small part of the iterator's job. But the object does not know anything about the iterator unless you define the class specifying the object in such a way that it knows the iterator. You might have circular reference problems with that, but the big problem is Iterators are not intended to be cached or stored. As a result it's dangerous to do so; one change to the container's content  and your iterators are worthless. Think on the cost of tracking N iterators to do updates to understand why.

Comment: I read above that this is for an assignment. Either you are misinterpreting what the instructor wishes you to learn, or the instructor has been consuming dangerously vast quantities of crack. Either way, this is an X-Y problem. Define what are you really trying to solve and let's see if we can come up with a better solution than the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

A list iterator is, by definition, an iterator into a list. It can only point to objects owned by a list. Your only choice is to put the object in a list so that you can get an iterator to it.

If the object is already in the list, find it in the list so that you get back an iterator to it. Note that storing iterators in classes is dangerous because many operations on a list invalidate iterators to it.